# how to serialize array of booleans

Tags: python, json, bson

i have a webservice written in python. and it gets invoked from angular code.in python code of the web-service, as shown below, the web-service returns `isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative` which is an array of boolean
. when the service is invoked from angular code i receive the `isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative` as string.
i want to receive the aforementioned array as an array the contains boolean value so i can iterate through its contents.
what the web-service returns and what the angular code shows is the following string :

```
isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative: "[false, false, true, true, false, false, true, true, true, true]"
```

i would like to receive it as an array of boolean.

**Note:**

it is not a numpy array. it is a normal array declared as follows:
isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative=[]

**update**:

```
for:  "pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment":np.array(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment,dtype=float).tolist()
i recieve the following error:

    TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

the pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment contains _pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment
            logger.debug(type(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment)):<class 'list'>
            logger.debug(type(pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment[0])):<class 'list'>
            logger.debug(type(_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment)):<class 'list'>
            logger.debug(type(_pixelsValuesSatisfyThresholdInWindowSegment[0]))::<class 'numpy.float32'>
```

**returned dictionary from python code as json**:

```
    resultsDict = {
        "isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative":json.dumps(np.array(isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative, dtype=bool).tolist())
        }
```

Comment: Why are you using numpy (`np`)?

Comment: So why do you use `np.array(...).tolist()`? It seems circular to from a list to a numpy array back to a list.

Comment: @ogdenkev because i recive Object of type bool_ is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't dump the list as string in your dictionary, also it seems you have some numpy data type which is not JSON serializable, convert them first:

```
resultsDict = {
    "isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative": [bool(x) for x in isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative]
}
```

Similarly if you have numpy floats, to make it JSON serializable:

```
resultsDict = {
    "isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative": [float(x) for x in isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative]
}
```

Comment: it the approach you provided can be also applicabe for an array of floats??if yes provide an example

Comment: What kind of example are you looking for ? It should be the same. I guess the only caveat here is that. numpy array is not serializable so convert it to list before sending it over the network.

Comment: Actually I'm having the same question as @ogdenkev, why are you using numpy here ? Can't you directly use `isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative` ?

Comment: i recive Object of type bool_ is not JSON serializable,when i only use isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative

Comment: What is `type(isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative)` ?

Comment: it is DEBUG:root:<class 'list'>

Comment: How about `type(isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative[0])` ? You need to make sure every element in the list is JSON serializable too.

Comment: it is <class 'numpy.bool_'>

Comment: Ahh, so that's where the error comes from. Same error as `json.dumps(np.False_)` I guess a more appropriate way is `list(map(bool, isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative))`, i.e. convert the np.bool_ (not JSON serializable) to python native bool (JSON serializable).

Comment: would you please have a look at the update section posted above

Comment: @LetsamrIt It seems under some cases, you have a list of list of floats. You might need to loop and convert each sub list as well.

Comment: @LetsamrIt but I guess the real fix is to figure out where the data comes from and convert them to python native types upstream.

Comment: would you please provid an example how to solve it

Comment: would you please answer this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69342526/how-to-serialize-an-array-of-floats

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I gather that the `isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative` variable is a NumPy array of dtype bool.

```
isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative = np.array([True, False, False, True])

resultsDict = {
    "isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative": isKeyWindowSegmentRepresentative.tolist()
}
```

If it is of type float, it should also work because floats are JSON serializable.

```
my_floats = np.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4])

resultsDict = {
    "my_floats": my_floats.tolist()
}
```

It may not work for every data type because [NumPy arrays are not JSON serializable](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/how-to-io.html?highlight=json#write-or-read-a-json-file).